# How to change a Command to your own one

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I want the `echo` command to be `say` or something else and the code will be like this `say("Hello World");` and so on but how to do that?

Here is what i tested:

This is a file called "Config.ini"

```
set echo=say
set cls=CLear
set @echo off=#Screen
```

and On the "Main.bat" file

```
#Screen
for /f "eol=- delims=" %%a in (Config.ini) do set "%%a"
CLear
say Hello
pause
```

I tried this but it didn't work, so does anyone know how to create your own Programming Language or atleast change some commands with Batch-File?

-And Thanks!

Comment: You're setting the variables backwards and you aren't calling them correctly. Look at the output of `set /?`. Also, because you have `set` in the .ini file and in the .bat file, the script is reading `set set echo=say`.

Comment: Create your own programming language? Well what you are doing is pretty far from that. You are simply creating variables in a very highlevel, existing scripting language.

Comment: That being said, you `set` the values the wrong way around. You cannot call `#screen` prior to getting the variables because they have not yet been `set`, as it is only being `set` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: "renaming" internal commands: no way. (external commands: yes, but surely not advisable) Alternative idea: build a "compiler" to translate your commands (`say`, `clear`, `#Screen' ...) to the corresponding `cmd` commands (and adapt the syntax). An ambitious project, but certainly doable in batch.

Comment: You could create [DOSKEY](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) macros.  You would essentially have to load them every time you needed to use them. So you would want to keep them in a macro file.

Comment: You can create aliases for existing commands, but why would you want to do it? It means that a professional who knows cmd.exe batch file scripting would have a more difficult time understanding your code. Is that really what you want? What do you see as the benefit of doing this?

Comment: @Squashman DOSKEY Macros don't work in batch files (because they are hooked to the keyboard (driver)).

Comment: @Stephan And how to create a compiler that need high Programming Languages and skills right? and if i made a compiler it will compile my commands (Say, #Screen ...) to the (echo, echo off ...) commands?

Comment: High Programming Languages? Depends on your desired syntax. Skills? Yes, would be useful. It will do, what you program it to do. Does it make sense? Very doubtful. Would more be the sort of "I do it because I can" project. (just out of curiosity: *why?*)

Comment: @Stephan Because i wanted to test if it possible to make a Not really a programming Language because it's not that easy, to make a batch file with his commands changed like the "echo" will be "say" and stuff....
So, is it possible?

Comment: not whithin batch.

Comment: @Stephan Okay, do you know what i need to do that, i mean what is the best Programming Language to use to create your own? btw thanks for all your answers

Comment: a lot of knowledge, how `cmd` works, a concrete idea, how your language  should work, what commands it should have, what parameters or switches they should have, how their output should be, what syntax they should have, ... Your question is like "I've got a screwdriver - how to build my own spaceship. What should I know?" Then decide, which (real) programming language you want to use (to build either a compiler or a replacement for `cmd`) and learn it (way better than "I have a basic idea how it works and I can do some basic stuff).

Comment: @Stephan Ok thanks for the advise, i will search a way to do that if i didn't find one i will change the entire subject.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you need to set variables the correct way around.

```
set "say=echo"
set "clear=cls"
set "#screen=@echo off"
```

Then calling the commands, you need to use the variable handler, `%` but you cannot call `#screen` as it does not yet exist until the loop.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (config.ini) do %%a
%clear%
%#screen%
%say% hello
pause
```

Comment: When i execute the file it says 'hello' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
-And is there any method to not use the "%" ?

Comment: There is no way to set variables and using them without % or ! When delayed expansion is on.